# My name is not appearing in closed notice

Tags: support, flags, closed-questions

Lately I was wondering why my name is not appearing in the **closed** notification for questions I flagged.

E.g: I flagged a question as "not constructive" and it get approved than the question is closed see the following screenshots:

[image]

In an other way, why my name isn't part of the list ? do I need some privileges to be listed ? or I'm just getting it wrong and *flagging* is **completely** different than *closing*?

Comment: flagging is completely different to closing, yes

Comment: thanks I got it now :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your name only appears if you physically cast a Close Vote (which requires 3000 reputation), not if you flag it for attention.

Comment: "...if you ***physically cast*** a Close Vote..." I think we seriously need some Stack Exchange Hardware. Like a small pad we can hit with a hammer to cast a close-vote, a little cat which we stroke when we want to upvote (would also work for Reddit) and not to forget that big, red, fat "NUKE" button which does downvote, closevote and flags it as offensive. Bonus points for the "Whip of Punishment" with which we can cast a closevote, downvote and kill the OPs guinea pig for asking such a bad question, all at once.

Comment: @Sulfurized that's a great gadget idea. Seriously. A USB punching bag style device or a "NUKE" button designed to withstand a lot of G's. It would take the hardware, and a browser extension. It would help channel aggression all over the world

Comment: And maybe some day, a USB-connected headset so we can **mentally** cast votes as well